# How view tail of log file in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, tail

I'm using the latest IntelliJ and want to be able to view the output of `ssh me@someserver.com tail somelogfile` in IntelliJ when remote debugging. How would I do this?

Comment: IIRC there's a terminal available (possibly as a plugin?) but... I have to say, you'd have a lot more functionality using a plain old terminal window.

Answer (score 8):

If you have Ultimate Edition, do the following (I dont think this is available in Community edition):

1) Specify remote connection settings (host, port, user, pass) in:
File > Settings > Build, .., Deployment

2) Add a remote external tool in File > Settings > Tools > Remote SSH External Tools

In "Connection Settings" choose the one created in step 1. In "Program" write "tail somelogfile".

Comment: consider "tail -f", if you want to watch the log file. Also, I had to write "/usr/bin/tail" in program and to specify parameters in the parameters text field

Comment: To clarify for anyone having issues like I was, you need to write `tail` into "Program" & `-f somelogfile` into "Arguments"

Comment: Although this solution works, the logging comes through a lot more "fluently" when connecting to the host yourself (Tools > Start SSH Session) and then doing the tail. This in Ultimate Edition 2019.1.3. (Yes, I know I'm behind.)